# Printing to smb with kerberos auth?

Tags: linux, samba, cups, kerberos

I want to set up a printer via linux samba client to a Windows printserver.

I managed to do it specifying this connection string:

```
smb://user:pass@printserver/printer
```

Is there a way to do auth through kerberos, without specifying `user:pass` as part of the uri?

This command:

```
smbclient -L printserver -k
```

works well (so samba itself is able to login through kerberos), but I didn't find out how to tell CUPS to apply kerberos authentication. I did not find such GUI options in KDE nor a way to specify it through the command line.

```
$ plasmashell --version
plasmashell 5.10.5
$ kf5-config --version
Qt: 5.9.1
KDE Frameworks: 5.38.0
kf5-config: 1.0
```

(duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/430315/, maybe here is a proper place)